# Copy selections from two related tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables in a database.  In the first table (tab1) I have a list of items.  In the second table I have a many to many relationship between these items.

```
CREATE TABLE tab1(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC,set INTEGER, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE tab2(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC,id1 INTEGER,id2 INTEGER,relationship TEXT);
```

The items in the first table are comprised of sets that all have the same value for the `set` field.  I want to duplicate any given set with a new set id, such that the new set contains the same elements and relationships of the original set.  If all the items in the set have sequential ids, I can do it as follows.  First, find the highest id in the set (in this case, set 3):

```
SELECT id FROM tab1 WHERE set=3 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

I assign this to a variable $oldid. Next, I duplicate the items in tab1 matching the specified set, giving them a new set (in this case 37)

```
INSERT INTO tab1 (set,name) SELECT 37, name FROM tab1 WHERE set=3 ORDER BY id ASC
```

I then get the id of the last row inserted, and assign it to the variable $newid:

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid()
```

I then assign $diff = $newid-$oldid.  Since the original set has sequential ids, I can simply select the original relationships for set=3, then add the difference:

```
INSERT INTO tab2 (id2,id2,relationship) SELECT id1+$diff,id2+$diff,type FROM tab WHERE id1 IN (SELECT id FROM tab WHERE set=3)
```

But this does not work if the set is not consisting of sequential ids in tab1.  I could do a complete query of the original ids, then create a 1:1 mapping to the newly inserted ids for set 37, and then add the difference between each row, and then insert the newly computed rows in the table.  But this requires loading all the selections to the client and doing all the work on the client.  Is there some way to create a query that does it on the server in the general case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `(set, name)` is a candidate key for `tab1`, you can use these columns to look up the corresponding values:

```
INSERT INTO tab2(id1, id2, relationship)
SELECT (SELECT id
        FROM tab1
        WHERE "set" = 37
          AND name = (SELECT name
                      FROM tab1
                      WHERE id = tab2.id1)),
       (SELECT id
        FROM tab1
        WHERE "set" = 37
          AND name = (SELECT name
                      FROM tab1
                      WHERE id = tab2.id2)),
       relationship
FROM tab2
WHERE id1 IN (SELECT id
              FROM tab1
              WHERE "set" = 3)
   OR id2 IN (SELECT id
              FROM tab1
              WHERE "set" = 3)
```

Comment: Looks like this may do it.  The id1 column looks good, but the id2 column appears to be the original ids, not the duplicated ids.  I tried replacing `id2` with `(SELECT id FROM tab1 WHERE set=37 AND name=(SELECT name FROM tab1 WHERE id=tab2.id2)) as id2` and this seemed to work.